# Should I use tomcat or a application server?

Tags: java, tomcat, web, server

I'm gonna start to develop a web application which will be accessed by 20-30  users simultaneously. I'll use a 2gb(ram) server and tomcat for a low memory comsumption. Can Tomcat solve my problem without the Java EE implementions and provide a good perfomance application? I don't want to use JPA, CDI and the other stuffs because of my little memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tomcat is an app server

[Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is indeed an [application server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server), providing a small subset of technologies included in other servers.

Tomcat implements several [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) (now known as [Jakarta](https://jakarta.ee)) specifications including:

- [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)
- [JavaServer Pages (JSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)
- [Java EL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language)
- [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Tomcat also includes [Coyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Coyote), a high-performance HTTP [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server).

For many people, these technologies are all they need to deploy their web app. If all you need is a [Vespa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespa), don’t buy a [Harley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley-Davidson).

## Pick 'n' mix

If you have need of some particular framework defined in Java EE / Jakarta, you can often add a library just for that one part, without all the rest. If you are tight on memory, this approach is better than installing another app server that loads many more frameworks than you need.

## Alternatives

If you like Tomcat, and want more of the Java EE / Jakarta features to be bundled for convenience, consider [Apache TomEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_TomEE). Falls short of the many more libraries included in other app servers, but may have all you need.

A close competitor to Apache Tomcat is [Eclipse Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)), another minimal app server focused on Servlet/JSP functionality. Both Tomcat & Jetty are well built, actively supported, and quite popular.

Comment: Thanks @Basil Bourque! Now I am confident. Tomcat will be my choice.